# Can I fit my selenium script into python gui application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, user-interface, selenium-webdriver

Suppose I want to make automation software for GMAIL using selenium in Python
I have made email id textbox , password textbox, from ,to,subject,body text box  and send button . if i am clicking on send button it should fetch data from text boxes and process auto login and send mail to the respective person.. 
Is it possible to do that using selenium and tkinter in Python? please tell me.

Comment: yes of coarse ... there might be some "are you a robot" type checks that will mess you up ... you should really use their Oauth api to send emails the way they want you to rather than trying to use selenium in a way that they dont really want you doing

Comment: I am making for my own website which do not include any captcha or verification and I have done this earlier in Visual Basic but as I am new to Selenium so I don't know about it, i am learning.